# What do the characters I've found on this old gun mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage, characters, character-identification

On an antique shotgun I was told had Korean origin I found the following (what I presume are Hanja?) characters<sup>†</sup>. Four out of five I believe I have correctly identified. One character I could not find in the dictionary.

Side A:

```
[UNKNOWN CHARACTER] 特 製
```

Side B:

```
絞 筒
```

The unknown character is three stacked components in this basic form

```
-------
   人  
-------
     
-------
   巾  
-------
```

Though, the bottom component might well be `中`; there is quite a bit of tarnish obscuring it.

On Side A, the two characters that follow the unknown one seem to indicate "special manufacture".

One Side B, I get the translation "hang" or "twist" for character one, and "tube" for character two. To me, this might indicate the process of [rifling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rifling), but I could not find any use of these characters on the [Chinese character entry for rifling](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%86%9B%E7%B7%9A), and the barrel is old and I couldn't tell conclusively if it'd ever undergone that process.

#### Can someone help me translate these characters?

<sup>† I Originally I [posted this on the Korean stack](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/what-do-the-characters-ive-found-on-this-old-gun-mean) because I thought they may use Chinese characters in some idiomatic way that might make it a more suitable place, but now I am thinking that probably doesn't make much difference, and also I am not confident about the gun's Korean origins so am posting here. Thanks.</sup>

## Edit

I was able to take some acceptable close up imagery:

[image: Side A]

[image: Side B]

Comment: A photo of the gun would be helpful. If this is not possible, please provide the stacked components in [ideographic description sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_description_language#Ideographic_Description_Sequences) format, as that would give a better indication of the spatial relationship between the components.

Comment: @droooze Updated.

Comment: I’ll refrain from answering twice, so see also https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/what-do-the-characters-ive-found-on-this-old-gun-mean.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Japanese character. By using Sogou Typewritting (Chinese) you can use this method to see any character that you can't pronounce:

for example, you wanna look at “特”
==type "u" + "niu"（→牛） + "si"（→寺）

——this would give you “特”

so I tried to type "u人布” or "u入布" and could not find this character.
So this might be a japanese character.

Answer (score 0):

these're kanji, japanese related :)

anyway, a shotgun (散弾銃) has barrel (筒); such barrel has two types, "平筒", or "絞筒".

here're several related web pages in japanese:

https://www.gunshop-urawa.co.jp/shooting/skeet/02.htm

https://ssl.yjl.co.jp/yjl/clay/rule-sg-cyoke.html

i would suggest op try to ask in japanese stack exchange :)

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely cross post over there. When you say, "such a barrel has two types", can you please explain the difference between `平筒` and `絞筒`?

Comment: not lah :( i 've no knowledge of gun, these two terms are kanji, japanese people would give you a more precise explanation than me. have fun :)